# FreeMarker modify existing file

Tags: java, file, freemarker

I want to modify an existing file with FreeMarker.
For Ex,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="$(package_name)">
  $(activities)
  <activity android:name=".map.activity.MapsDemoActivity" />
  <activity android:name=".map.activity.MapListActivity" />
  <activity android:name=".map.activity.EventsDemoActivity" />
  <activity android:name=".map.activity.InfoWindowDemoActivity" />
  <activity android:name=".map.activity.CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity" />
</manifest>
```

In above code I want to update the $(package_name) and  $(activities).

I'm using **org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.23**, Need to do this file modification using Java program.

I know how to create new file using free maker but unable to modify existing file using java program.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: don't understand.. you want to update the `.ftl` template file with a Java program? It's text, so open file, read lines, look for the text you want to replace, etc..

Comment: No, not like that. Let me explain with an example,
I've an existing File-1.java and I want to add some code in it (say a method). So will create File-2.java.ftl with the placeholder.
Now I want to merge the contents of File-2.java.ftl into File-1.java.

Similar code merging is done in Android Studio, when we create new activity it adds the activity.java, layout.xml and merge its values in strings.xml and manifest.xml.

Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

Use merge command in the recipe.xml

```
<merge from="root/src/AndroidManifest.xml.ftl"    
to="${escapeXmlAttribute(manifestOut)}/AndroidManifest.xml" />
```

In root/src/AndroidManifest.xml.ftl
you just specify the elements that you want to insert